# Is there a way to avoid an array allocation?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, fortran, fortran95

I need cells index numbers, which fulfil following conditions:

```
    Q(i)<=5 and V(i)/=1
```

(size(Q)==size(V)). I wrote something like this:

```
    program test
    implicit none
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:):: R 
    integer Q(5)
    integer V(5)
    integer counter,limit,i

     counter=0
     limit=5
     V=(/0,0,1,0,0/)
     Q=(/5,10,2,7,2/)

    do i=1,5
      if((Q(i)<=5).AND.(V(i)/=1)) then
          counter=counter+1
      end if
    end do

    allocate(R(counter))
     counter=1
    do i=1,5
      if((Q(i)<=5).AND.(V(i)/=1)) then
          R(counter)=i
          counter=counter+1
    end if
    end do 
    deallocate(R)
    end program test
```

but I don't think it is  a very efficient . Is there any better solution for this problem?

I can remove one loop by writing

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable, dimension(:):: R
  integer Q(5)
  integer V(5)
  integer counter,limit,i

  counter=0
  limit=5
  V=(/0,0,1,0,0/)
  Q=(/5,10,2,7,2/)
  V=-V+1
  allocate(R((count(V*Q<=5)-count(V*Q==0))))

  counter=1
  do i=1,size(Q)
    if((Q(i)<=5).AND.(V(i)==1)) then
      R(counter)=i
      counter=counter+1
    end if
  end do
end program test
```

Comment: Do you mean something like in http://stackoverflow.com/q/21208593/3157076?

Comment: Yes, it's a similar problem to mine, but it also uses "allocatable". Maybe "linked list"?
Is it more practical solution?

Comment: One _could_ use a linked list, but that's quite likely to use even more involved dynamic memory management.  For simple cases like this I tend to measure "efficiency" in terms of "how long does it take me to write correct code".  In that case the answers to the other question - knocking the two loops down to one line - do that.  If you have other considerations then please elaborate in the question.

Comment: Do you mean delete one loop?I have made some changes: 
  program test
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable, dimension(:):: R 
  integer Q(5)
  integer V(5)
  integer counter,limit,i

   counter=0
   limit=5
   V=(/0,0,1,0,0/)
   Q=(/5,10,2,7,2/)

  V=-V+1
  allocate(R((count(V*Q<=5)-count(V*Q==0))))
  counter=1

  do i=1,size(Q)
    if((Q(i)<=5).AND.(V(i)==1)) then
        R(counter)=i
        counter=counter+1
     end if
  end do 

  end program test

My plan is solving this case, then create a subroutine, which I want to use in other program.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very close to being a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21208593/3157076) but explaining why would be a cumbersome comment.

Answers to that question take advantage of a common idiom:

```
PACK((/(i,i=1,SIZE(mask))/), mask)
```

This returns an array of 1-based indexes corresponding to `.TRUE.` elements of the logical array `mask`.  For that question `mask` was the result of `arr.gt.min` but `mask` can be any rank-1 logical array.

Here, mask could well be `Q.le.5.and.V.ne.1` (noting `Q` and `V` are the same length`).

In Fortran 95 (which is why I'm using `(/../)` and `.ne.`) one doesn't have access to the modern feature of automatic array allocation, so a manual allocation will be required.  Something like

```
logical mask(5)
mask = Q.le.5.and.V.ne.1
ALLOCATE(R(COUNT(mask))
R = PACK((/(i,i=1,5)/),mask)
```

As an incentive to use a modern compiler, with Fortran 2003 compliance enabled, this is the same as

```
R = PACK((/(i,i=1,5)/), Q.le.5.and.V.ne.1)
```

(with appropriate other declarations, etc.)

When considering doing this creation in a subroutine it is exceptionally important to think about array bounds if using non-1-based indexing or subarrays.  See my answer in the linked question for details.