# How to avoid explicit loop containing `a(i)=b(i,c(i))`?

Tags: fortran, vectorization

You can code your run-of-the-mill vector addition as a do loop, with a symbolic: index or with no index at all (in F95). I guess this makes no difference for the compiler anyway. Unfortunately, I have a nested statement, like:

```
do i=1,n
  a(i)=b(i,c(i))
end do
```

Of course `a=b(c)` is illegal. Any ideas to get rid of the explicit do loop?

Comment: This might be helpful, depending on how your `c` matrix is setup: [Fortran - Logical Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173960/fortran-logical-indexing).

Comment: The loop looks fine to me. Well readable. No reason to make a complicated single line ezpression. I changed the title. You are welcome to adjust it, but please let it describe the actual question and not some broad topic.

Comment: Also, I am not sure what `b` is. Is it an array? Is it a function? Just a one line code samole is usually not enough. All variables should be properly declared.

Comment: your proposed vector assignment doesn't even make sense. Would be something like `a=diagonal(b(:,c))`  (assuming a hypothetical intrinsic to extract a diagonal).   Anyway maybe `forall` would make you happy.

Comment: You could theoretically use an implied loop inside the expression instead of the outer explicit loop. But it would just make it uglier. And it does contain an index anyway.

Comment: @Vladimir F: Yes, a,b,c are just simple arrays. (2D,1D,1D)

Comment: I wonder if this works `a(:) = b(:,c(:))`

Comment: @ja72 `b(:,c(:))` produces a rectangular array with its diagonal elements the ones we want.

Comment: @agentp - then use `a(:) = diag( b(:,c(:)) )`

Comment: Please edit the question with some example data so we can tests solutions.

Comment: that's what i was getting at before, fortran doesn't have an intrinsic to extract a diagonal.  You could write one of course, but then how is that better than the original loop?

Comment: Exactly. (Also the problem is sort of moot inasmuch parallelization with OpenMP needs explicite loops, to my best knowledge.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Theoretically it does not need them (`omp workshare`) but in practice it mostly does.

Answer (score 0):

**Update :** after some more thinking, you can actually just use an implied-do array constructor (which is not explicit). This would just be

```
a = (/ (b(i,c(i)), i=1,SIZE(c)) /)
```

or

```
a = [ (b(i,c(i)), i=1,SIZE(c)) ]
```

See [section 4.8](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) of the standard.

*Original answer below using reshape and pointers.*

It can be done without a loop, but it is ... very questionable if this is good practice.

First of all you need to know that arrays are stored in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

This implies that on an array of size `(/ n,m /)`, element `(i,j)` is located at memory position `i + n*(j-1)`. So all you need to do is reshape and extract, which you can do in the following way :

```
  d = RESHAPE(b,(/ SIZE(b) /))                    ! reshape
  a = d((/ (i,i=1,SIZE(c)) /) + (c(:)-1)*SIZE(c)) ! extract
```

It does not require a loop, but you do have to allocate a bit more memory. Unless you hack your way into the memory. This can be done with a pointer

```
  TYPEOFB, POINTER, DIMENSION(:) :: p
  p(1:SIZE(b)) => b(:,1)             ! just close your eyes
  a = p((/ (i,i=1,SIZE(c)) /) + (c(:)-1)*SIZE(c))
```

**Example program :**

```
PROGRAM reshape
  IMPLICIT NONE
  !-- declaration of variables -----------------------------
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(4,3),TARGET :: b  !< target for pointer
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(4) :: c,a,a2
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(12) :: d
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: p  !< ugly pointer
  INTEGER :: i,j
  !-- setup of the test case ------------------------------
  c(1)=3; c(2)=2; c(3)=1; c(4)=2
  DO i=1,4
     DO j=1,3
        b(i,j) = i + 4*(j-1)
     END DO
  END DO
  !-- reshape and extract ---------------------------------
  d = RESHAPE(b,(/ SIZE(b) /))                    ! reshape
  a = d((/ (i,i=1,SIZE(c)) /) + (c(:)-1)*SIZE(c)) ! extract
  !-- ugly pointer hack -----------------------------------
  p(1:SIZE(b)) => b(:,1)             ! just close your eyes
  a2 = p((/ (i,i=1,SIZE(c)) /) + (c(:)-1)*SIZE(c))
  !-- print output ----------------------------------------
  DO i=1,4
     PRINT *, i, b(i,c(i)), a(i), a2(i)
  END DO
END PROGRAM reshape
```

**Output :**

```
 % ./a.out 
 1 9 9 9
 2 6 6 6
 3 3 3 3
 4 8 8 8
```

Comment: Of course you can use an implied loop, I already mentioned that in the comments. It is no better than the original code though and it certainly is not *"with no index at all"* which the question wants. It just moves the index somewhere else. And has some potential to make the computation slower.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it's possible. You can use EOSHIFT or CSHIFT to put the appropriate elements in the first column and then use RESHAPE to extract the first column. But it's inefficient because the compiler might shift around all the elements of the array instead of just size(b,1). Here is my example, which is hard for me to read.

```
program permute
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: N = 5
   dimension b(N,N)
   integer i
! Initialize matrix to arbitrary value
   character :: b = reshape([(achar(i+96),i=1,size(b))],shape(b),order=[2,1])
   character(30) fmt
   integer c(size(b,1))
! Output matrices
   character a(size(b,1)),z(size(b,1))
   write(fmt,'(*(g0))') '(a/(',size(b,2),'(a)))'
! Print out input matrix
   write(*,fmt) 'b =',transpose(b)
! A sample permutation
   c = [1,3,4,5,2]
   write(fmt,'(*(g0))') '(a/(',size(b,1),'(a)))'
! Matrix a will have the output we want to emulate
   do i = 1, size(b,1)
      a(i) = b(i,c(i))
   end do
   write(*,fmt) 'a =',a
! Matrix z gets its result as specified in text. Is it correct?
   z = reshape(eoshift(b,c-1,dim=2),shape(z))
   write(*,fmt) 'z =',z
end program permute
```

Comment: Cool that I got a downvote for being the only poster that answered the question as written.